# selecting the complete default text by a mouse click

Tags: qt

I have a **QLineEdit** widget in my **menubar** which shows the text **"search by ID"** by default. How can I implement a MouseClicked event handler for the QLineEdit, such that when I click on the LineEdit widget, the default text is cleared and user can enter the text that he wants to search?.

so far

```
#ifndef SEARCH_H
#define SEARCH_H
#include<QLineEdit>

class search : public QLineEdit
{
        signals:
                void clicked();

        protected:
                void mousePressEvent(QMouseEvent *);
};
#endif
```

Comment: Your question is not very clear. Please edit it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You just need to connect QLineEdit::mousePressEvent ( QMouseEvent * e ) signal with function. When this signal will be emited, clear QLineEdit in your function. Simply, isn't it?

EDIT

Or if u have

```
void mousePressEvent(QMouseEvent *);
```

in your widget, all what you need is write definition for that method. When user press mouse over QLineEdit, this function will be invoked. Like:

```
void search::mousePressEvent(QMouseEvent *e)
{
    myQLineEdit->setText("");
}
```

EDIT 2

Then try to do it this way:

```
class YourWidget : public QLineEdit
{
    Q_OBJECT

    protected:

    void focusInEvent(QFocusEvent* e);
};
```

and

```
void YourWidget::focusInEvent(QFocusEvent* e)
{    
    if (e->reason() == Qt::MouseFocusReason)    
    {
      myQLineEdit->setText("");
    }

    // You might also call the parent method.
    QLineEdit::focusInEvent(e);
}
```

Comment: i tried but its not working and also giving error that e parameter unused @Blood

Comment: just a small error error: invalid use of incomplete type âstruct QFocusEvent

Comment: if(e->reason() == Qt::MouseFocusReason)

Comment: Okey, so just delete it. It's unnecessary in your case.

Comment: By the way i have checked code of my first edit and it worked so i don't know what u did

Comment: is this happening because i have declared myQLineEdit globally??
because i am using this variable in my other fuction create_menu with which i am adding this lineedit into the the menu bar with the help of QDefaultWidget

Comment: Lolz :D Yes, that's the reason. Your QLineEdit should be declared in search class. If u need to use it in other functions, you should solve this in other way.

Comment: then please can you help me in that case.as the othe function in which i m using line edit is of other class declared as class box:: public QDialog
now what should i do because if i will not declare it globally then how can i use an element of a particular in other class

Comment: Please create new topic with question because we it's hard to talk via comments ;)

Answer (score 0):

You'll want to use the [QLineEdit::placeholderText](http://qt-project.org/doc/qt-4.8/qlineedit.html#placeholderText-prop) property. It shows a grey text which disappears when the user starts editing it (i.e. when it gains focus).

```
QLineEdit * edit = new QLineEdit;
edit->setPlaceholderText("Search by ID");
```

Comment: He want to know how to clear QLineEdit after user press mouse over it not how to set text.

Comment: @Blood It seems more likely he wants to implement a placeholder text. That functionality is already available in QLineEdit, why reimplement it?

Comment: ya placeholdertext is something i want but it says it was added in QT 4.7.no such command found